# Harmonic functions on varifolds

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, geometric-measure-theory

Let $T$ be a $k$-dimensional varifold in a Riemannian manifold $M$. Assume that $f$ is a smooth function on $M$ which is weakly (sub-)harmonic on $T$; that means that
$$
\int \langle \nabla_\omega f,  \nabla_\omega \varphi \rangle dT(x,\omega) = 0 \,\,(\leq 0)
$$
for every compactly supported smooth function $\varphi\geq 0$ on $M$. A prime example is when $M = \mathbb{R}^n$, $T$ is stationary and $f$ is a coordinate function; then $f$ is a weakly harmonic function on $T$. Are there any maximum principles that apply for weakly (sub-)harmonic functions on varifolds? I would be grateful for a reference where I can learn about this.

Added: What I am particularly interested in knowing is the following: Let $T$ be a stationary integer rectifiable varifold in a Riemannian manifold $M$ and let $f$ be a smooth function on $M$ which is weakly sub-harmonic on $T$. Assume that there exists a point $x \in \operatorname{spt}(T)$ such that $f(x) = \sup_{y \in \operatorname{spt}(T)} f(y)$. Can one conclude that $f$ is a constant on the connected component of $\operatorname{spt}(T)$ which contains $x$?

Comment: Maybe of interest: Tom Ilmanen's paper on the strong maximum principle, Lemma 4 in particular. (Cool paper regardless, and it seems like the kind of thing you'd be interested in.)